# How to get a reference for TITLE, in chrome.contextMenus.create onClick function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get a reference for chrome.contextMenus.create title property in onClick function.

For example:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "sometitle", "contexts":["selection"], "onclick": searchSelection});

function searchSelection(info, tab){
    var query = "<i want title (sometitle) here>"+info.selectionText;
    var url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+query;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
}
```

I searched, but found no option doing this.

---

+1 Question: is there a way to inline edit contextMenu item? Or append an editable input field after CM element? I think no, but worth for a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no existing API method to retrieve information about a given menu item, since this information is rarely needed, and already available to the extension's developer.

Here's a general-purpose function to achieve the result:

```
/**
 * Creates a menu item using chrome.contextMenus.create.
 * When the second argument is specified, the click handler receives a
 *  third argument: The original creation data.
 * When the "onclick" property is set in the creationData, the "onclick"
 *  event does not receive a third parameter.
 *
 * @param object creationObject    Basic creation object
 * @param function onclickHandler  "click" property of the creationObject
 */
function createMenuItem(creationObject, onclickHandler) {
    if (onclickHandler) {
        creationObject.onclick = function(onClickData, tab) {
            onclickHandler(onClickData, tab, creationObject);
        };
    }
    return chrome.contextMenus.create(creationObject);
}

// Usage:
createMenuItem({"title": "sometitle", "contexts":["selection"]}, searchSelection);
function searchSelection(info, tab, creationData) {
    var query = "<i want title " + creationData.title + " here>" + info.selectionText;
    var url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
}
```

And no, there is no way to add an inline-editable menu item (the only available options are mentioned in [the documentation, `chrome.contextMenus.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create)).

Comment: Thanks, but it wasnt working for me, contextmenu item doest listed:(

Comment: Anyhow, i wanted this functionality, only becouse, i could save lines with it, this extension is a simple google dorks launcher, and if i could get the title, then if title is `site:techpowerup.com` then one function is enough, i could construct the query like: title+selectionText -> results `site:techpowerup.com selectionText` . Now, i have 4 function, 1-1 for different sites. By the way thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: @Jim-Y There was a typo in the code. I replaced } with ). It should work now.